# Testig MVC web applicatio with IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am asp.net MVC beginner and I started testing tiny MVC web app using IIS express. 
In asp.net web forms I had to upload /bin folder + webconfig + global.asax + all .aspx files

I would like to know what app core files have to be uploaded to IIS in order for app to work (/bin, /views, webconfig.aspx, global.asax). If I understood right View replaces Web form (.aspx file), and all the "code-behind" logic is compiled in bin folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio has a build in [Publish tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983453%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which you should rely on for this task.  This removes the need to work out which directories contain dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

> If I understood right View replaces Web form (.aspx file), and all
>   the "code-behind" logic is compiled in bin folder.

Yes

> I would like to know what app core files have to be uploaded to IIS in
>   order for app to work (/bin, /views, webconfig.aspx, global.asax).

One simple way to find out answer to this questions (by yourself) is to right click MVC project in Visual Studio and publish it to local filesystem. There you can find the published content and get to know which files needs to be taken to server.